# Calculate Latitude and longitude more between Latitude/Longitude points?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, math, location

Latitude: 22.744812,
Longitude: 75.892578

The above would be considered my center point.

And now I need to determine the latitude and longitude points from center point 1000 meter outward to each NSWE corners. So I would have a central long/lat, N, S, E and W long/lat..

So I would end up with 4 additional lat/long pairs.

What I am trying to resolve is a formula, preferably that can be done on a standard calculator to determine these 4 NSWE points based on the central point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use MapKit for that:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D *) calculateSquareCoordinates:(CLLocation*)center withRadius:(float)radius{

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center.coordinate, radius*2, radius*2);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D  points[4];

    points[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta/2, region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta/2);
    points[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude + region.span.latitudeDelta/2, region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta/2);
    points[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude + region.span.latitudeDelta/2, region.center.longitude + region.span.longitudeDelta/2);
    points[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta/2, region.center.longitude +  region.span.longitudeDelta/2);

    return points;
}
```

and just call

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *fourPoints = [self calculateSquareCoordinates:center withRadius:1000];
```

on your code.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the Lat/Long based on distance from a starting Lat/Long. have a look at this [Link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Answer (score 0):

The average radius of the earth is around 6371000 metres.  This means that

1 degree of lattitude is equivalent to 6371000 * PI / 180 metres

(NB: PI = 3.14159... etc).  However, 1 degree of longitude depends on the lattitude that you are.  At the equator, one degree of longitude corresponds to the same distance in metres as 1 degree of lattitude.  However, at the north and south poles, all longitude values are the same point (i.e. the pole itself), so 1 degree of longitude at the poles is zero metres.  The formula for longitude is

1 degree of longitude is equivalent to 637100 * PI / 180 * COS(Lattitude)

where COS is the trigonometric cosine function.  If you make these conversions, then you can do the calculation on a standard calculator.  However, be aware that these are approximations that work well over short distances (e.g. less than a few hundred kilometers), but  over long distances (e.g. thousands of kilometers) they become more and more inaccurate.